# Menu with ToggleButtons

Tags: wpf, togglebutton

I would like to create window when in left panel is menu (with toggle buttons) and in right panel are views. When I click in toggle button, visible the view and another views will be hidden. But my code do open view despite himself.
This is my code:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
     <ToggleButton Name="Button1" Checked="MenuItem_Checked">
     <ToggleButton Name="Button2" Checked="MenuItem_Checked">
</StackPanel>
<administration:View1 Grid.Column="1" 
                              Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                              Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<administration:View2 Grid.Column="1" 
                              Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Button2, Path=IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                              Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
    private void MenuItem_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var el = sender as ToggleButton;
        if (Equals(_current, el))
            return;
        _current = el;
        foreach (var menuChild in Menu.Children)
        {
            ToggleButton button = menuChild as ToggleButton;
            if (button == null) continue;
            if (!Equals(button, _current))
                button.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
<View1.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="View1">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
 </View1.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

i guess, setting IsChecked as false in loop causing this issue,because if you have any UnChecked defined and set "_current" there, during second iteration _current may hold the unchecked ToggleButton, put a breakpoint there and check for yourself, you can avoid this by including flag like below,

```
 bool internalChange = false;
    private void MenuItem_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!internalChange)
        {
            var el = sender as ToggleButton;
            if (Equals(_current, el))
                return;
            _current = el;
            foreach (var menuChild in Menu.Children)
            {
                ToggleButton button = menuChild as ToggleButton;
                if (button == null)
                    continue;
                if (!Equals(button, _current))
                {
                    internalChange = true;
                    button.IsChecked = false;
                    internalChange = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I designed a custom window chrome, flyout menu and toggle button. when toggle button IsCheced property set to true, flyout menu opened with nice animation and when toggled off flyout closed.

1. Show State
   [flyout menu is open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEw2w.jpg)
2. Hide State
   [flyout menu is closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFKij.jpg)